# how to set automatically decimal values using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change the number into integer and decimal portions after specific length. For example if I am entering more than 8 digit balance digits should be displayed as decimal values.

**input :**

> 4567454857

**output:**

> 45674548.57

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `Numbers` without a decimal portion (ie, they look like ints) can be easily converted to decimals through division (JS isn't like other languages where ints can't become floats). However, for your problem, I have a solution involving substrings and the ability to convert freely between `Number` and `String`.

```
function truncateToEightDigits(num) {
    if (num > 99999999) { // if num has more than 8 digits
        var str = String(num);
        return Number(str.substr(0, 8) + '.' + str.substr(8, str.length));
    } else {
        return num;
    }
}
```

This also has the added benefit of avoiding weird issues with floating point math you might incur if you tried to do something such as divide by 10 repeatedly.

Side note: I'm not really sure what this has to do with ASP.NET and I'm kinda wondering why you tagged your question with that.